# How to create stacked bar chart using C3 for string data?

Tags: bar-chart, c3

I am trying to created stacked bar chart using C3 chart. But i am facing problem as i am trying to plot a graph with string values.
 My data looks like this

```
var data1=["Country", "Denmark", "India"]
var data2=["Value", 1, 1]
var X=["Item",'Item1','Item2]

c3.generate({
             data: {
                x:'Item', 
        columns:[[data1],[data2]],
                 type: 'bar' ,
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2']
        ]
    },);
```

I just want to display the values using the tooltip functionality of C3-chart.Is there a way to make my bar chart independent of the y-axis?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could do something like this: http://jsbin.com/dowogejose/1/edit?html,js,output

Basically set a value of 1 for each country:

```
columns: [
  ['Denmark', 1],
  ['India', 1]
]
```

Then set the callback function on the tooltip format to get the value from a lookup:

```
tooltip: {
  format: {
    value: function(value, ratio, id, index) {
      var lookup = {
        'Denmark': 123,
        'India': 456
      };
      return lookup[id];
    }
  }
}
```

You could even store the lookup value outside of the tooltip callback, and generate the columns array using this object.